# extra space in sed output which impact other script

Tags: sed

Need to remove extra space in sed command

I was able to get string after $$ENV$$_ in file with below command

```
sed '/.*$$ENV$$_/!d;s///;s/,.*//;s/^[ \t]*//' file.txt
```

am executing command as:

```
TAB=$(sed '/.*$$ENV$$_/!d;s///;s/,.*//;s/^[ \t]*//' $file.txt)
```

and this variable($TAB) i am passing on different command to replace value in different file with the command:

```
cat backup.txt | sed 's%\$\$BTABLE\$\$%"${TAB}"''%g' > $file_bkp1.txt
```

but in my output, I'm getting an extra space.

**file.txt**

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE $$ENV$$_TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE , NO FALLBACK , 
    NO BEFORE JOURNAL, 
    NO AFTER JOURNAL, 
    CHECKSUM = DEFAULT, 
    DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKADSRATIO
```

**Sed command to fetch value from file.txt**

```
TAB=$(sed '/.*$$ENV$$_/!d;s///;s/,.*//;s/^[ \t]*//' file.txt)
```

Command to replace value (from: $$BTABLE$$) to (TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE)  from backup.txt

```
cat backup.txt | sed 's%\$\$BTABLE\$\$%"${TAB}"''%g' > file_bkp.txt
```

**backup.txt** **Input file**

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE $$ENV$$_$$BTABLE$$_NEW ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      AR_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
      AR_TO_RTE_TY_RL_TY_ID VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      RTE_BASIS_TY_ID VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      RTE_TY_ID VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      RTE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
```

**Output of file_bkp.txt with extra space at end which highlighted in bold letter**
**Output file**:

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE $$ENV$$_TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE _NEW ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      AR_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
      AR_TO_RTE_TY_RL_TY_ID VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      RTE_BASIS_TY_ID VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      RTE_TY_ID VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      RTE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Can you give only clear input file and desired output?

Comment: update input and output file, let me know if you still not clear

Answer (score 0):

Get the tag with

```
TAB=$(sed -n 's%.*\$\$ENV\$\$_\(.*\)_NEW.*%\1%p' file.txt)
```

This uses `-n` to skip printing of all lines except those explicitly designated for printing. The `p` flag in the substitution says "print this line if a substitution occurred".

Furthermore, for the line we're interested in we filter out everything except the exact substring we're interested in by surrounding the substring with `\(..\)`. Then in the substitution we can pull the text inside those parens with a "back-reference": `\1`.

With this value, do the substitution with:

```
sed 's%\$\$BTABLE\$\$%'"${TAB}"'%g'
```

This is just a slight variation of your command with some tweaks to the quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with the input here:

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE $$ENV$$_TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE , NO FALLBACK ,
```

The sed script `sed '/.*$$ENV$$_/!d;s///;s/,.*//;s/^[ \t]*//'` would first
remove that `$$ENV$$_` (`/.*$$ENV$$_/!d; s///`), then remove anything after the comma (`s/,.*//`), and then remove any leading spaces (`s/^[ \t]*//`), but not the space before the comma. So the output is `TEMP_ESM.EMPASGMTAMPTMPRTRSE␣`, with a trailing space (`␣`). I think that space carries on in your output.

I think you could change that last substitution to `s/[ \t]*//g` (remove the `^` anchor, add the `/g`) to remove any and all remaining whitespace anywhere in the string.